# tkinter code is not working on raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am developing the following tkinter code on windows machine(and is working), but when moved to raspberry pi(Pyhton 3.2) , did not work. It does not get any error (on the shell) and the console print is working. The actual GUI is missing.....

I tried with other smaller tinker program and is working fine.
On raspberry pi, I go to menu, programming, idle 3 , open file and execute it.

Is there any log file that I can check?

The code basically has 2 pages, on first page I show two varibles aux[0] and aux[1] . These values are captured under update funcion through a serial COM.
Meter class is the actual gauge graph.
In update function you can see the print function, that shows these values in the shell . This is working.

Any idea what might be wrong?

```
import serial
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkf
import math

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
data = [20, 15, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 23,12,4,2,0,9,4]
c_height = 350

velocidad_total=0
direccion_total=0
i=0

direccion=[]
velocidad=[]
ser = serial.Serial('COM2')# ttyUSB0
ser.baudrate = 9600

class Meter(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self,master,tod,*args,**kwargs):
        super(Meter,self).__init__(master,*args,**kwargs)

        #tod='day'
        self.layoutparams(tod)
        self.graphics(tod)
        self.createhand(tod)
        self.setrange()


    def layoutparams(self,tod):
        # set parameters that control the layout
        height = int(self['height'])



 def set(self,direccion,velocidad):
        # call this to set the hand
        # convert value to range 0,100
        #deg = 300*(direccion - self.start)/self.range - 240
        self.itemconfigure(self.textid,text = str(velocidad))
        rad = math.radians(direccion-90)
        # reposition hand
        self.coords(self.handid,self.centrex+30*math.cos(rad)
        ,self.centrey+30*math.sin(rad)
        ,self.centrex+self.handlen*math.cos(rad), self.centrey+self.handlen*math.sin(rad))
        #self.coords(self.handid,self.centrex+25*math.cos(rad-0.31),self.centrey-15*math.sin(rad-0.31)
        # ,self.centrex+15*math.cos(rad+0.31),self.centrey-25*math.sin(rad+0.31),self.centrex+90*math.cos(rad),self.centrey-90*math.sin(rad))



    def blob(self,colour):
        # call this to change the colour of the blob
        self.itemconfigure(self.blobid,fill = colour,outline = colour)

the meter class continues. Omited to make this as short as possible

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        #label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label.grid(column=0,row=0)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="HISTORIA",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        #button.pack()
        button.grid(column=0, row=1,sticky=(E) )
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="NOCHE",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        #button2.pack()
        button2.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W))

        self.print_value()

    def print_value(self):

        w=Meter(self,height = 400,width = 400,tod='day')

        #w.pack()
        w.grid (column=0, row =3,columnspan=3,rowspan=3)
        if len(direccion)!=0:
            w.set(int(direccion[-1]),int(velocidad[-1]))


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()

        self.imprimir()

        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=400, height=400, bg = 'white')
        self.canvas.pack()



def update():
        global velocidad_total
        global direccion_total
        global i
        c = StringVar()
        c=ser.readline()
        aux2= str(c, 'utf-8')
        aux = aux2.split(" ")
        direccion.append(int(aux[0]))
        velocidad.append(int(aux[1]))

        velocidad_total = velocidad_total+velocidad[i]
        direccion_total = direccion_total+direccion[i]
        if (i>299): # para retener 5 min de estadisticas que llegan c/u 1seg
            i=0
            velocidad_media= velocidad_total/300
            direccion_media = direccion_total/300

        print (aux[0]," ",aux[1])
        #theta.set(c)
        #w.set(aux[0],aux[1])
        app.after(100,update)


app=SeaofBTCapp()
app.after(100,update)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this is to create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will require you to remove as much code as possible while still seeing the problem. Eventually you'll remove something and the error will go away. You'll then know what code is causing the problem. '

My guess is that it's simply waiting for data on this line of code:

```
c=ser.readline()
```

Comment: Bryan, thanks for your help. I do get the values through the COM because I see them in the print command. BTW, what is "mcve"